# Changing frame in print composer of QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I made a map based on a raster from [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/tag/world-file/) web site with some vector layers with the Qgis software.
When I compose this map I cannot get the right size: there are too big or to small as you can see in the photos. I tried to change all the setting in the composer, but does not work.

Can anywhere, please, can explain how to crop the frame in the composer so I can get rid of the white border?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is **Resize page to content** option in *Composition* tab (QGIS 2.18). You can set the margins and click on the *Resize page* button.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I head change the size like you said, but it I was only able to make the white border bigger instead of smaller. Can you explain some more about this function?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you want to crop page size to map item, select the map item, left the margins 0.00 and only hit the *Resize page* button. If my answer solved your problem, you can say "thanks" by accepting (or upvoting, in general case) the answer :)

Comment: Sorry, but I an still don't get it. Its look like I am missing the "select item" step.

Comment: I don't think this is problem in your case, if you have only one map item, this item will be automatically selected. Also you have active *Item properties* in your screenshot, which means the item is selected. See how it works in my new gif in answer.

Comment: @OtoKaláb out of curiosity, which tool did you use to create the gif?

Comment: @LaughU its Peek  - https://github.com/phw/peek

Comment: I've got a similar funciton but can't find the appropriate commands in 3.28.15