# Why does my map have a big white square around map?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I am trying to make a printable map with print composer. Why does my map have a big white square around map?
[image: Print composer]

Comment: You mean the _page_? Perhaps this post might help: [How can I change the frame in the print composer in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240519/how-can-i-change-the-frame-in-the-print-composer-in-qgis)

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The print composer has a page, then you add elements such as a map.

Your map is not aligned to the size of the page, so that's the first problem.

The white space around your image is simply because the scale of your map isn't zoomed to fill the entire map element.

So you should fit the map element to the page first, then adjust the scale of the map to fit the entire map element.

Comment: And if for whatever reason you need the map element to be that big but would like to get rid of the white background within the element, you can uncheck "Background" under Item Properties.