# Crop space in Print Layout in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I want to crop spaces in the print layout in QGIS. How do I manage this?

[image]

Comment: Right click on the page on select page properties, see the documentation here : https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/overview_composer.html#updating-page-properties

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the frame in the print composer in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240519/how-can-i-change-the-frame-in-the-print-composer-in-qgis)

Answer (score 1):

You can resize your layout to the size of your content with only two simple steps :

1. Define position and size of all your component : for each component (map, image, scale, text) in your layout go to tab **item properties** and set **Position and size**. You can also resize and move with your mouse.
2. Then go to **Layout** tab and then **Resize layout to content** and then click in the button <kbd>Resize layout</kbd>

[image]

If you have a specific layout size you can also set it. First right-click on your page then go to **page properties** and define the page size you want and if you want white background or not.